# Can a pilot fly past their 12 hour "Regularly Scheduled Duty Day" of 135.267(c) if they stay within the legal 14 hour max limit?

Tags: commercial-operations, flight-schedules, far-135, medevac

**Can a pilot who is assigned a regularly assigned duty day under .267(c) of 12 hours, be assigned a flight on the 12th hour (right before they would normally go home) which would cause the pilot to fly in their 13th hour of Duty? (Below the legal maximum 14 hour duty limit)**

Background info:

I am looking to learn more about .267(c). The internet does not seem to hold much information on it, except that many believe it is a schedule that almost no one uses.

Many folks interpret 135.267(c) as the permission to exceed flight times in .267(b), and while that is true, it is within a context of a different crew schedule, called the "Regular Scheduled Duty Day".

From “Berry 2009” FAA Legal interpretation:

> Certificate holders may establish flight crew member schedules under
> the "moving 24 consecutive hour" flight time limitations of §
> 135.267(b), or the regularly assigned duty period of no more than 14 hours flight time limitations of § 135.267(c). - “Ross 1993”

While it does not explicitly say it, .267(c) is meant to resolve the issues of the rolling 24 hour flight time limitations, under specific circumstances.  While crew members may not exceed the same daily flight time (8 hours single pilot), they can exceed the 8- in-24.

Ex.  Pilot flies 8 hours from 10am to 6pm on Monday, then on Tuesday, starts flying at 8am.  This would exceed the 8-in-24, but if it is during a regularly scheduled duty day under .267(c) this is perfectly legal.

"Regularly assigned duty day” is defined as:

> “comes to work and… goes home at the same time every day” - “Berry
> 2009”
>
> "regularly assigned duty periods are not intended to be implemented
> for short periods of time." - “New 2013”
>
> “A schedule of at least four weeks a reasonable amount of time to
> establish a regularly assigned duty period." - “New 2013

From “Berry 2009”:

Hypothetical Regularly assigned duty period of 0600-1800

> "If the 'day' pilot who began his 'availability' at 0600 was
> 'notified' for a flight assignment at 1600 and reported to the
> airport, what is the latest time he can operate an aircraft under FAR
> Part 135 without violating section l35.267(d)? Should he be concluded
> by 2000 (14 hours from 0600), or can he operate the aircraft until
> 0600 the next morning (14 hours from the time he was 'notified')?"
>
> “This answer assumes the hypothetical company is operating single
> pilot flight crews. In this situation, because the flight crew
> operates under a regularly assigned duty day, the provisions of 14
> C.F.R. § 135.267(c) apply. Under section 135.267(c), a regularly
> assigned duty period may not exceed 14 hours. Section 135 .267(d) does
> not apply in this situation because it pertains to unscheduled part
> 135 operations not using regularly assigned duty periods. Accordingly,
> the pilot in your hypothetical must conclude flight time by 2000 hours
>
> - 14 hours from the start of his regularly assigned shift. See Legal Interpretation 1993-21 (Aug. 30, 1993). Note that although 14 hours is
>   the maximum length of a regularly assigned duty day prescribed by
>   regulation, operators, such as the one in your hypothetical, may elect
>   to use a shorter duty day.”

The question above indicates that the person asking the question is confused about how all the different parts of 267 work together, including that (d) does not apply to (c).

However, although the regularly assigned duty day is 0600-1800, which is less than 14 hours, the FAA does see that the pilot is allowed to fly to 2000 (the legal limit of 14 hours of duty).  Which means the pilot did not go home at 1800, like they normally do.

**Do you have experience using .267(c)?  If so, please state so in your responses.  Thank you.**

Comment: I think if they were at home spending time with the family and just making sure they were near the phone and didn’t get called until 1600 and then maybe didn’t arrive at the airport and report in until 1700 then their duty time starts at 1700.   I think a regularly assigned shift includes reporting for duty and maybe hanging around the break area while waiting for an assignment.  But regularly assigned duty does not include lounging by the pool at home waiting for a call even if you are “on-call”.

Comment: Thanks for you response Jim.  FAA legal interpretation makes it clear that "on-call" is on duty, and where you spend the time (at the pool, or in the break room) does not factor into that.  However, I will not go into that further, as it does not pertain to my question.

Comment: hmm ok.  I read the FAA’s def of duty period “*Duty period means the period of elapsed time between reporting for an assignment involving flight time and release from that assignment by the certificate holder. The time is calculated using either Coordinated Universal Time or local time to reflect the total elapsed time.*”  where it says “reporting for an assignment”  ...

Comment: Maybe it’s my understanding of “on-call” that’s defective.

Comment: Yes, you have found the definition of duty that continues to confuse operators to this day.  The definition of "rest" is needed to further understand where Duty comes into play, because you cannot be resting, if you are on duty, and you cannot be on duty, if you are resting.  However, there are many FAA legal interpretations that further clarify this.  Since you're asking, I have provided a link below to one of them.  https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2009/Berry_2009_Legal_Interpretation.pdf

Comment: This one might actually be clearer.   https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2009/Mayors_2009_Legal_Interpretation.pdf

Comment: They may be bureaucrats but they aren't all stupid, they know companies abuse loopholes. 
The USDOT (of which the FAA is a branch) also has different categories of rest. (Explicitly used in trucker regulations. Possibly ships and trains too.) Simply being off of the clock is not sufficient for certain definitions. One type of rest logged is only valid if during a continuous period while physically in sleeping quarters and not on call, so time eating dinner or traveling to/from the hotel wouldn't count.  So even if not FAA explicit, there is common law to consider in the definition of rest.